# Stop a loop at input "0" in C

Tags: c

I am trying to make a loop in which the user is asked for car models and years. The loop is supposed to end with input "0", but I cannot make that work and instead the loop keeps going on.
My code looks like this:

```
char model;
int year;

while (model != '0') {
   printf("Input model name (0 quits): ");
   scanf("%s", &model);
   if (model == '0') {
      break;
   } else {
      printf("Input year: ");
      scanf("%d", &year);
      ...
```

I have also tried using atoi() and isdigit(), but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: `model` is uninitialized at the start of the loop on the first iteration.

Comment: also `model` is a char, so you should be using the `%c` format option with `scanf`, rather than `%s` which is for strings.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &model);` is a recipe for undefined behavior. Even a single input character will overwrite memory you don't own (two are actually stored: one for the char, one for the terminator, and you're passing it memory for exactly *one*). If you're reading a single char why aren't you using `fgetc(stdin)` , storing in an `int`, and testing for EOF rather than assuming the read worked?

Comment: Please read up on the difference of `"%c"` and `"%s"` for scanf.

Comment: `char` holds *one* and only one character, not a C string.

Comment: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Answer (score 0):

Hello undefined behavior.

Ok then the problem is passing the address of a single char to `scanf` with `%s`. That doesn't work very well.

We want something like:

```
    char model[16];
    while(1) { /* or your preferred infinite loop here */
        printf("Input model name (0 quits): ");
        fgets(model, 16, stdin);
        if (model[0] == '0') break;

        /* continuing on your input */
        printf("Input year: ");
        scanf("%d", &year);
      ...
    }
```

So what we do is read in the line with `fgets` and check for the 0 after and break out of the loop on 0. This code follows your lead and doesn't sanitize your input.

There's no good way to do this with a single character read because you need to get rid of the newline.

I actually recommend converting the whole thing to `fgets()` but one step at a time.